# Mysql: Trim number to be between X and Y MIN/MAX

Tags: mysql

I don't know the terms or the exact word used for this, but I'm looking for a function inside MySQL that can trim a number to be between X and Y.

For example, something like this:

```
SELECT TRIM_NUMBER(NUMBER, MIN, MAX);
```

If I do: `TRIM_NUMBER(50, 1, 100)` it should be fine, and return `50`.

But if I do something like: `TRIM_NUMBER(999, 1, 100)` it should return `100`, because it's the MAX value I'v set it to. The same thing should apply for MIN.

Is there any such function included in MySQL ?

Comment: How would this function be useful - and why would a WHERE function not work in this case?

Comment: I need to use this in a complicated SELECT query, (not in the WHERE part)thank you

Comment: What about processing the number beforehand, on the server side, using PHP for example?

Comment: It's a huge SELECT query, sometimes it's best to do it in MySQL side. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT GREATEST(LEAST(NUMBER, 100), 1);
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know this functions existed! +1

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything built in, but your code it yourself, like this:

```
select if(num < 1, 1, if (num > 100, 100, num))
```

Comment: fisharebest's solution looks cleaner, but thank you for the help very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you want the "overkill" of a function, here's a suggestion:

```
create function trimNumber(x double, floorValue double, ceilValue double) returns double
begin
   declare ans double;
   if x >= floorValue and x <= ceilValue then
       set ans = x;
   else
       if x < floorValue then
           set ans = floorValue;
       else
           set ans = ceilValue;
       end if;
   end if;
   return ans;
end
```

Comment: Definitely fisharebest's is a better (cleaner and shorter) answer

Comment: Thank you very much ! I also agree !

Comment: Why not just return the expression in the accepted answer? This amount of code is ridiculous.

Comment: @Bohemian That's why I said "overkill"

Comment: I thought the "overkill" was creating the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like that(from MySQL Reference Manual):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: this only returns "true" or "false".. not sure if it's what I need.

Comment: I have no mySQL server to test it right now:
SELECT 50*(50 BETWEEN 1 AND 100);

Comment: Not sure you got what I mean.. it's not working sorry. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this because it is the ANSI standard way of expressing this:

```
select (case when num < 1 then 1
             when num > 100 then 100
             else num
        end) as TrimmedNum
```